# Can I assign a click event to a path in an SVG with React?

Tags: reactjs, svg, path, onclick

Let's look at my simple code and talk about it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as SouthAmerica } from "./assets/South_America.svg";

const StyledSouthAmerica = styled(SouthAmerica)`
  path {
    fill: ${(props) =>
      props.fillColor}; // Change the color to whatever you want
    stroke: ${(props) => props.stroke};
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
export default function Geomap() {
  const [isGeomapSelct, setIsGeomapSelct] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Button clicked!");
    setIsGeomapSelct(true);
  };

  return (
    <StyledSouthAmerica
      fillColor={isGeomapSelct === true ? "#C9E9E1" : ""}
      stroke={isGeomapSelct === true ? "#61AD96" : ""}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <path />
    </StyledSouthAmerica>
  );
}
```

I don't want to give the SVG component a click event, I want to fire the onClick event on the path tag

I've tried using onClick in the pathtag but it's not working at all, is it possible to fix this, please help.

Comment: Can you share what's going on in `SouthAmerica.svg`? If it has a `ReactComponent` defined in it then it doesn't seem like a regular svg file ...

Comment: The code inside the SVG file is too long to show, is there a way to show the file itself?

Comment: The actual content of the SVG is not really important, but it would be nice to see the React code which is wrapping it. It seems possible that e.g. the component accepts a `children` prop, but does not render the children within the component. In this case, your `<path/>` is not accepting a click handler because it's not being rendered at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of css `pointer events` property, set `all` for `paths` and `none` for  rest of the area other than paths.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as SouthAmerica } from "./assets/South_America.svg";

const StyledSouthAmerica = styled(SouthAmerica)`
 //Here set to none
  pointer-events: none;
  & path {
    fill: ${(props) =>
      props.fillcolor}; // Change the color to whatever you want
    stroke: ${(props) => props.stroke};
   //Here allow only for paths
    pointer-events: all;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

export default function Geomap() {
  const [isGeomapSelct, setIsGeomapSelct] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Button clicked!");
    setIsGeomapSelct(pre=>!pre);
  };

  return (
    <StyledSouthAmerica
      fillcolor={isGeomapSelct === true ? "#C9E9E1" : ""}
      stroke={isGeomapSelct === true ? "#61AD96" : ""}
      onClick={handleClick}
    ></StyledSouthAmerica>
  );
}
```

Note that passing `fillColor` in camelCase won't be recognized by the DOM. Instead, use `fillcolor`.